# Deserilization MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId with Json.Net return incorrect result

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, deserialization

```
    var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjectId.GenerateNewId());
    var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectId>(serialize);
```

`deserialize` contains an invalid value {000000000000000000000000}

```
MongoDB.Driver(2.4.4)
Newtonsoft.Json(10.0.2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are the contents for the variable serialize,  and ObjectId.GenerateNewId()

Comment: serialize is string {"Timestamp":1504826067,"Machine":2930047,"Pid":6256,"Increment":8602945,"CreationTime":"2017-09-07T23:14:27Z"}

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions running this code?

Comment: No. The code is executed without exceptions

Comment: This might be because all the properties of ObjectId are readonly, so you might want to deserialize into another object(maybe via `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType`), then initialize the ObjectId using it's constructor.